# public Boolean isAdmin in Asp.Net Mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

```
public Boolean isAdminUser()    
{    
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)    
    {    
        var user = User.Identity;    
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();    
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));    
        var s = UserManager.GetRoles(user.GetUserId());    
        if (s[0].ToString() == "Admin")    
        {    
            return true;    
        }    
        else    
        {    
            return false;    
        }    
    }    
    return false;    
}
```

My problem in Asp.Net Mvc 6, `GetRoles` and `GetUserId` does not exist, in MVC 5 have two of these, due to the version of assembly: `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`. Can someone help me to correct this problem?

### As mentioned above code, I execute I encounter as follows:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'optionsAccessor' of 'UserManager.UserManager(IUserStore, IOptions, IPasswordHasher, IEnumerable>, IEnumerable>, ILookupNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber, IServiceProvider, ILogger>, IHttpContextAccessor)'    LMS.DNX 4.5.1   D:\Projects\Library\LMS\src\LMS\Controllers\RoleController.cs   50  Active

// UsersController
[Authorize]
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager _userManager;
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public UsersController(
            UserManager userManager
            )
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

```
    }
    // GET: /Role/Users
    public async Task<IActionResult> IsAdminUser(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userId = User.GetUserId();
                ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
                if (!IsAdminUser())
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    private bool IsAdminUser()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userId = User.GetUserId();
            var user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user.ToString() == "Admin")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    // method is async and returns a Task
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = User.Identity;
            ViewBag.Name = user.Name;
            //  ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            //  var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

            //var s=    UserManager.GetRoles(user.GetUserId());
            ViewBag.displayMenu = "No";

            if (IsAdminUser())
            {
                ViewBag.displayMenu = "Yes";
            }
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Name = "Not Logged IN";
        }


        return View();
    }
}
```

// RoleController

[Authorize]
    public class RoleController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager _userManager;
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public RoleController(
            UserManager userManager
            )
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

```
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {


            if (!IsAdminUser())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        var Roles = _context.Roles.ToList();
        return View(Roles);
    }

    // GET: /Role/Users
    public async Task<IActionResult> IsAdminUser(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userId = User.GetUserId();
                ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
                if (!IsAdminUser())
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    private bool IsAdminUser()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userId = User.GetUserId();
            var user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user.ToString() == "Admin")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {


            if (!IsAdminUser())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        var Role = new IdentityRole();
        return View(Role);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(IdentityRole role)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (!IsAdminUser())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        _context.Roles.Add(role);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I fix the IsAdminUser with the new method, code has no error, I still don't have good result, if anybody know how to fix it. Note with thank.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30701830/1663001

Comment: upgrade your asp identity version

Comment: I think UserManager have `UserManager.GetRolesAsync()`

Comment: I have tried UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Name, "Admin"), but it does not work. This code is in UserController.cs.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the user is in role with following code.

```
if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```