# How to get userid in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

we are using asp.net core and in we are unable to get user id directly so here is working code

```
var UserID = this.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims?.ToList().Where(x => x.Type == "MembershipId").SingleOrDefault()?.Value;
```

if there is any way to get userId directly from User.Identity let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current logged in user Id ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701006/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-user-id-asp-net-core)

Comment: Hi the solution is for Asp.Net and i want solution for ASP.NET Core and given solution is not working for asp.net core

Comment: All solutions are for dot net core can you try var userId = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

Comment: yes i tried its not working

Comment: can u debug that and show us what errors are getting generated?

Comment: If that doesn't work, the user is not logged in.