# How to set IdentityUser as a ForeignKey?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is my class briefly:

```
public class UploadFile
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TinyBlog2User User { get; set; } //this user is extend from IdentityUser
    public byte[] md5 { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    public string ThumbnialUri { get; set; }
}
```

Then I upload a file and save the file-url to database like this way:

```
 UploadFile uploadedFile = new UploadFile()
                        {
                            md5 = md5Value,
                            Uri = fileBlob.Uri.ToString(),
                            User = currentUser,
                            ThumbnialUri = thumbnailBlob.Uri.ToString()
                        };

                        _dbContext.uploadFiles.Add(uploadedFile);

                        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But in my uploadFile table  'userId' column is always null.
I am new comer to ASP.NET Core, can you tell me what is going wrong with my code?
Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"then it always be null"*? What operation? If reading from database, it won't be populated automatically - see [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). You'd probably need to use `Include` method.

Comment: thanks for your answer, my mean is the column in database don't has value,it's null. I'm not good at English,I hope you don't mind. And I upload a picture to question.hope you can get my point.

Answer (score 0):

In the extend from IdentityUser write

```
List<UploadFile> UploadFile {get; set;}
```

and in upload file

```
public int UserId {get; set;}
```

Here type should the the id type of User Table and property name should be TableName+Id

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it when I go home.

Answer (score 0):

Write your `UploadFile` model as follows:

```
public class UploadFile
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; } 
    public byte[] md5 { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    public string ThumbnialUri { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; } //this user is extend from `IdentityUser`
}
```

Then in the `DbConext` configuration.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<UploadFile>()
            .HasOne(uf => uf.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(uf => uf.UserId);
}
```

Now run a brand new migration!

And modify your FileUpload method code as follows:

```
UploadFile uploadedFile = new UploadFile()
                    {
                        md5 = md5Value,
                        Uri = fileBlob.Uri.ToString(),
                        UserId = currentUser.Id, // Here set the current logged in UserId
                        ThumbnialUri = thumbnailBlob.Uri.ToString()
                    };

                    _dbContext.uploadFiles.Add(uploadedFile);

                    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Note: If you need how to get current logged in `UserId` then [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701006/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-user-id-in-asp-net-core/52135130#52135130)

Comment: Thank you bro!I'll try it when I go home.Have a nice day :)

Comment: Okay! Let me know your feedback!