# How can I get my own User in controller in Asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have User class:

```
public class User : Entity
{

    public void AcceptMenu(Menu menu)
    {
      //AcceptMenu 
    }      
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And I create authorization logic. Authenticate method looks like this:

```
      private async Task Authenticate(User user)
    {

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Login),
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, user.Role)
        };

        ClaimsIdentity id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
    }
```

As you can see I have AcceptMenu method in User. How can I get User in Controller and execute AcceptMenu method?

Comment: @AntonToshik, Which function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller has property User with `IPrincipal` type. You can get name of user with `User.Identity.Name`  But it is name of Authenticated asp.net user. You can map this  Authenticated user with your user class.
in controller

```
ApplicationUserManager UserManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

ApplicationUser  user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);
```

Where ApplicationUserManager is class with identity config , and ApplicationUser is IdentityUser from this class. But it is not your db User derived from entity class, it should be mapped manually

Comment: Are you suggesting get user like: `var user = appContext.Users.Single(a => a.Login == User.Identity.Name);` ?

Comment: Yes it is correct way, also you could use  [dbo].[AspNetUsers] but it is not extendable approach

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `var loggedInUser = await useManager.GetUserAsync(User)` to get the user if you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

[How to get the current logged in user Id in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701006/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-user-id-in-asp-net-core)
Once you get the value from ClaimsPricipal, you can pass the value as a parameter.