# User.Identity.GetUserId() always returns null in .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

I am using Microsoft Identity. But in my code the Identity method **User.Identity.GetUserId** always return null.

Here is my code.

```
private string GetUserId()
    {
        string userId = "";

        try
        {
            if (_identity != null)
                userId = _identity.GetUserId();
            else
                userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }

        return userId;
    }
```

Comment: Please see [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52135130/1797425) post, it may be of help...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current logged in user Id in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701006/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-user-id-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

`User.Identity.GetUserId()` no longer exists, but the id is available as a claim on your principal.

The first and easiest is just pull out the claim:

```
userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

If you have an instance of `UserManager<TUser>`, then you can use the `GetUserId()` method on that using DI:

```
userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
```