# How to get IdentityUser.Claims after update from .net core 1 to 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identityserver4

I first had some fun chasing down why my IdentityUser was complaining it had no UserName property. I needed the Identity.Stores assembly to sort that one out.

But I can't find any reference to what changes were made between core 1 and 3 in reference to claims management. My DBContext and UserManager use to take care of this and the IdentityUser had a Claims property but default but now this isn't the case so am getting "User does not contain definition for Claims". Is this an easy fix and am I missing another dependency assembly? or is this a breaking change?

I've seen reference the ClaimsIdentity but I need IdentityUser attributes and am trying to up rev in the simplest of ways but this one has caught me out and can't find any reference to them removing claims for IdentityUser.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: is this helpful ?  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063000/asp-net-core-3-1-user-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-findfirstvalue

Comment: Sorry no. Not at first glance. The Claims property has been removed so there must be some form of advice as it's a breaking change to previous code. It might have changed from 1 to 2, and not just 3. Regardless though I can't find what the new design intention and implementation is.