# How to assign an object, for example, the owner's car

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I can not understand. I have a registered account, for registration using asp indentity. And I want the user to be able to add cars to himself without the field for choosing the owner of the car from the name of his account, so that it would add itself.Can you please explain the implementation or send a code example, you can also link to the source of how to do it.

Comment: Is your question "how do I get the logged in user id in a controller method?"

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yes

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701006/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-user-id-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Thank you for your help, the question is a bit silly but Im also a newbie)