# get the Id from token or claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization, auth0

I use `Auth0` for authentication and authorization with the backend `.Net core` for frontend React applications. I am trying to get the logged-in user Id or email using httpContextaccessor in the `API` for logging purposes. But getting the value like this `auth|374634....`. Below is the code for the same. I am unsure whether I consider this an Id after this part `auth|`

```
public interface IUserIdProvider
{
    string? GetUserId();
}
public class UserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserIdProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetUserId()
    {
        var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        return userId ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I get the information below when I watch the info near userId [image]

Please let me know how to get the logged-in user id or user email in API.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Would the following help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701006/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-user-id-in-asp-net-core