# Getting the "Current User" with Okta

Tags: c#, okta

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Our company uses Okta for SSO. I have a stand-alone (non-web) application. I am trying to find out if the "current user" running the app is already signed in to Okta. If so, I want to get the SAML assertion so I can eventually make an AWS call. (I'm not worried about taht part yet.)

I have the Okta SDK for .NET. Unfortunately, there seems to be no documentation that I can find for how to *use* the API (version 7.0.2). I only see references to GitHub repos. This is why I have no sample code posted.

Basically, I am just trying to validate if the current user is signed in; and, secondarily, where to find SDK documentation. Looking at method signature in VS Object Browser is not documentation.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you have a standard controller on the server (see : https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp).  There are many postings on How To Get User ID in a controller.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701006/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-user-id-in-asp-net-core

Comment: There is no controller. As I said in the posting, this is not a web app.

Comment: AWS is Amazon Web Services.  You are making a AWS call!!!  It may not be a web app but you are still making an HTTP connection and you have a HTTP Client and HTTP Server.

Comment: The HTTP Client and all the underlying HTTP "stuff" is hidden by the AWS .NET SDK. A stand-alone application can easily make HTTP requests. The point I was trying to make when mentioning the app is not a web app was that I want to use the Okta SDK (which, I realize makes HTTP calls). I am looking for Okta SDK example/documentation.

I was not claiming that there is no HTTP involved, but that the app itself does not receive HTTP requests (i.e., there is no Controller or Action methods).

Comment: You want just a Backend application where you are using SAML to get data from OKTA SDK.  The first link I provided does just that plus has the controller code.  You just don't need the controller.